# How to use an Iconfiguration service as Idisposable in .net core as Coverity shows a resource leak?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, coverity, sast

I am using IconfigurationRoot service using Build() function.

```
IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json"));
var configservice = builder.Build();
```

Now this works, but the problem is since Configuration service cannot be treated as IDisposable, how do I prevent the resource leak happening in Static Analysis Security Test? How to dispose of `configservice`?

I tried 'using' method or using Dispose() but it can't be used as such methods can only be used with Idisposable or IdisposableAsync.